# Onvif device (camera) is not found during discovery

Tags: web-services, cxf, onvif

I'm working on Camera firmware to support ONVIF specs (using Java). I'm using Apache CXF to run services. I've imported `remotediscovery.wsdl` and `devicemngmt.wsdl` and created services for them.

I'm sure the services are running and bound to SOAP UDP:

```
Starting Server
[Fatal Error] addressing:2:2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
28.11.2014 16:01:12 org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean isEmptywsdl
28.11.2014 16:01:12 org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromClass
INFO: Creating Service {http://www.onvif.org/ver10/network/wsdl}DiscoveryService from class org.onvif.ver10.network.wsdl.DiscoveryLookupPort
28.11.2014 16:01:13 org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl initDestination
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be http://localhost:8080/onvif/device_service
28.11.2014 16:01:13 org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
INFO: jetty-8.1.15.v20140411
28.11.2014 16:01:13 org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector doStart
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@localhost:8080
28.11.2014 16:01:13 org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromWSDL
INFO: Creating Service {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01}Discovery from WSDL: classpath:/org/apache/cxf/ws/discovery/wsdl/wsdd-discovery-1.1-wsdl-os.wsdl
28.11.2014 16:01:13 org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl initDestination
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be soap.udp://239.255.255.250:3702
28.11.2014 16:01:13 org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromClass
INFO: Creating Service {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01}DiscoveryProxy from class org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.DummyImpl
Starting Server
28.11.2014 16:01:31 org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromWSDL
INFO: Creating Service {http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl}DeviceService from WSDL: /tmp/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl
28.11.2014 16:01:51 org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl initDestination
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be http://localhost:8080/onvif/DeviceService/device
Starting Server
[Fatal Error] addressing:2:2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
28.11.2014 16:01:58 org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean isEmptywsdl
28.11.2014 16:01:58 org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromClass
INFO: Creating Service {http://www.onvif.org/ver10/network/wsdl}DiscoveryService from class org.onvif.ver10.network.wsdl.RemoteDiscoveryPort
28.11.2014 16:01:58 org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl initDestination
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be http://localhost:8080/service/DiscoveryService/discovery
Server ready...
```

I've tested it using CXF `WSDiscoveryClient` and they can be found:

```
16 clients found
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><EndpointReference xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><Address>http://localhost:8080/onvif/device_service</Address><ReferenceParameters/></EndpointReference>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><EndpointReference xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><Address>http://localhost:8080/onvif/DeviceService/device</Address><ReferenceParameters/></EndpointReference>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><EndpointReference xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><Address>http://localhost:8080/service/DiscoveryService/discovery</Address><ReferenceParameters/></EndpointReference>
...
```

But I can't see my device using SmartICRSS or any ONVIF client.

What's wrong? I expect my device to do discovered by WS-Discovery and then I expect `probe` method to be invoked by client. I have breakpoint in and it's not invoked.

PS. I've installed network traffic interceptor app and found that production IPCameras response with `ProbeMatches` response (in soap body) and CXF's impl does not reply. How can I make CXF service reply with `ProbeMatches`?

Answer (score 2):

WS-Discovery is not ONVIF, it is a XML SOAP WS-Discovery

http://specs.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/ws-discovery.pdf

And, the version you have to use: April2005 version11

Please refer
https://code.google.com/p/java-ws-discovery/

Comment: I heard Onvif are using WE-Discovery standard to discovery device.